# Cannot Get Error Code From HTML <img> Tag

Tags: html, image, error-handling, fetch, browser-cache

I attempted to use the HTML `img` to fetch my image and dealed with error when fetch failed in different error code (404, 503).

But it seems not possible know the error code from server via this approach (shown below).

Is there any approach that can achieve this.

```
// in a React Component

const handleOnLoadError = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}


// return ...
<img
     className={imageClasses}
     onLoad={handleOnLoad}
     onError={handleOnLoadError}
     src={imageURL}
 />
```

While I did try to write my own `fetch` and feed the result blob as `src` to `img`, it works but the browser stop cache my API response. Contrary, If the API is sent from `img`, it somehow cached in browser.

I want to preserved the cache design but want to **handle different error code like 503 or 404 from server.**

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

That's only possible using `Image`. i.e

```js
const img = new Image();

img.onerror = () => { /* handle error */ }
img.onload = () => { /* handle load */ }

img.src = imageURL;
```

Comment: the `onerror` function only received an `Event` parameter that only has these properties (isTrusted, type, target, currentarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelBubble, cancelable, defaultPrevented, returnValue, srcElement, timeStamp)
there seems no way to know the error code from API

Comment: But I do notice from [mdn window error event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event). It seems the window `onerror` can receive much more info than `Image.onerror`.

Comment: What kind of information are you looking to get out of that?

Comment: the image source will be given a URL and I want to handle the server response (like 503, 404) solely by HTML `<img>` without using `fetch`.   @Joshua

Comment: If that's what you want, then fetch is the way to go. Why don't you want to use fetch?